# Are square brackets valid in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am looking at a note that someone wrote to me and it looks something like this:

```
SELECT Something FROM Foobar WHERE blah='blah'  --- [pulls this too - SELECT Something FROM Foobar WHERE something='elsehappens']
```

I'm trying to figure out if the `--- [ comment - QUERY]` is just a comment or if it actually means something I haven't seen before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is just a comment...   square brackets are often used to delimit real names for reserved words, or simply to delimit actual identifiers, but anything after a `--` is always a comment.

Comment: Brackets are also used to treat space-separated words as one. E.G. if a column is called Text Entry you would have to do SELECT * FROM [Text Entry]

Comment: @Nick, that's dependent on the SQL server, though.  I believe MySQL uses back ticks instead of square brackets.

Comment: anything after -- on the same line is always a comment

Comment: Can also to be used as character classes in an regex like expressions: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field like 'caf[eéèëê]'`

Answer (score 0):

They are generally used to indicate optional words or clauses. In this example, it appears to be nothing more than a comment as indicated in the manual: [MySQL Comment Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html)

Answer (score 0):

In `MySQL`, a `--` comment is just a comment.

`C`-style comments with special characters may be used to give hints to the query optimizer, run version-specific queries etc:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT) /*!50000 ENGINE=InnoDB */ ;
```

This will create the table as `InnoDB` in `MySQL 5.0` or higher, or with default engine in `MySQL` below `5.0`.