# MySQL count rows in multiple date ranges?

Tags: mysql, date, count, range

I want to count the rows in several date ranges (i.e: last hour, today, this week, last 30 days) from a given table.

I need to know how many entries are in this time/date periods to be able to tell if a given user has reach the limit for each one of this ranges. For instance, a user can have max 300 entries one month but with a (hourly/daily/weekly/monthly) limit.

So far I'm trying with a subquery approach using a `SELECT CASE` similar to this one: [group by range in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687534/group-by-range-in-mysql)

Which should be the best way of doing this?

Comment: How do you currently store this information? Is it in a datetime field? You should be able to select pertinent parts using datetime functions and grouping. Providing structure for what you have and the result you want would help greatly.

Comment: yes, is stored using datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In mysql you could use a series of count functions with if statements so that only the required  dates are counted, like so.

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), 1, null)) AS hourHits,
```

and so on

***Edited as per comments***

Comment: You'll want to use `NULL` as the false condition since `COUNT()` will still count `0` into its calculation, otherwise, use `SUM()`. Also, I believe `<` should be switched to `>` or it will count all hits that *weren't* within the hour.

Comment: Zane is right, this is the actual COUNT:
`COUNT(IF(date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), 1, NULL)
) AS hourHits,`