# How to group by date ranges by five 5 minutes?

Tags: date-range

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [group by range in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687534/group-by-range-in-mysql)

I want to `count(*)` between specific ranges by dividing them into 5 minutes. For example

- start time **13-03-2012 10:30**
- end time **13-03-2012 10:45**

this time range should be splitted into 3 ranges and specifically count them

For Example:

### Ranges      Count(*)

range 1     5
range 2     7
range 3     11

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function, that returns a datset.

Parameters could be starttime, endtime and the number of intervals.

PseudoCode:

```
declare return @return table --- temp table
for 1 to intervalCount
   calculate start and endtime of interval
   select @c=count(*) from tbl where time between intervalstart and intervallend
   insert into @return (@c)
end for
```

I hope this gives you an idea. Please tell us which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I want to use TSQL
by the way thanks :)